# How can I synchronize Google Maps, Wikipedia, Mapmyindia, and Bing Maps data on one webpage?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, wikimapia

I want to combine maps from Google maps, Wikimapia, Mapmyindia and Bing maps on one web page with synchronization like in [Dual Maps](http://www.dualmaps.com/).

For example, if I pan on Google maps it should show the same location on all maps.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all maps have an API first! Then what you need are event listeners, especially for the dragstart, drag and dragend events. (These are from Google Maps API v3)
If you declare an event listener for an event, say for the drag event, there is an object returned in the function. Again, in google maps api v3 it is the event object, which has the latLng property which is an object of google.maps.LatLng type (ergo this contains the coordinate).
So you should declare these event listeners for all the map instances on your page and you should include commands to change all the other map instance's center/zoom etc. in each of the event listener functions.

I hope that the above made sense to you but if you have any questions feel free to ping me!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. @Tamas. I am not a Programmer but understand Google map API Code to some extent.Can you do this for me. if i got one. will definitely pull myself into it.  thanks Once again.

Comment: To what extent are you familiar with Javascript and Google Maps API? I can help you of course, but I am not sure if this is the right place to change contact details. Am I right?

Comment: I know only the basic. can say myself as "Beginner", i am just started learning it.if i have source code for it. it will be great.   thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [openlayers](http://www.openlayers.org/). You can create multiple divs, with a map in each div and update all of the other maps based on the one which is changed.